# Android : code to check/uncheck all checkboxes in listview on a single button click

Tags: android

how check/uncheck all checkboxes  in listview on a single button click when you are using listview with SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: You should be able to get the children of a viewgroup, iterate over them, and modify the check state of those which are checkboxes.

Answer (score 6):

```
for(int i=0; i < list.getChildCount(); i++){
    ViewGroup item = (ViewGroup)list.getChildAt(i);
    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)item.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id);
    checkbox.setChecked(true);
}
```

Here ViewGroup is the ViewGroup you used for list items

Comment: This seems to assume that there's a checkbox with the same fixed ID within each of a collection of viewgroups which are in turn children of a parent listview.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes... for custom list item there will be a single layout for item. which will have a single checkbox.. I assumed that ( i usually do that)

Answer (score 0):

try with this code::

```
private void removeAllChecks(ViewGroup vg) {
    View v = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++){
    try {
        v = vg.getChildAt(i);
        ((CheckBox)v).setChecked(false);
    }
    catch(Exception e1){ //if not checkBox, null View, etc
        try {
        removeAllChecks((ViewGroup)v);
        }
        catch(Exception e2){ //v is not a view group
        continue;
        }
    }
    }

}
```

Pass your list object to it. Just avoid really long and complicated lists.

Comment: If non-checkbox children are remotely common, it would probably be better to test for them before trying to cast to a checkbox, rather than rely on exceptions to handle a routine case.